# How the parameter `NumberOfConcurrentThreads` is used in `CreateIoCompletionPort`

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading, winapi

Looking at the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363862(v=vs.85).aspx) for `CreateIoCompletionPort` we read:

> NumberOfConcurrentThreads [in]
>
> > The maximum number of threads that the operating system can allow to concurrently process I/O completion packets for the I/O completion port. This parameter is ignored if the ExistingCompletionPort parameter is not NULL.
> >
> > If this parameter is zero, the system allows as many concurrently running threads as there are processors in the system.

However, the documentation I find gives no indication that the `IoCompletionPort` actually *creates* any threads.

In fact, the [example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppAsynchronousIO-a3f7c07d/sourcecode?fileId=21543&pathId=1497322710) Microsoft provides uses the following code to determine how many processing cores are available (instead of passing `0` in for `NumberOfConcurrentThreads`) and then actually creates that many threads.

```
// The general value of the thread count is the system's processor count.
SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo = { 0 };
GetNativeSystemInfo(&sysInfo);
const DWORD dwThreadCount = sysInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;

// A class in the example that wraps around IoCompletionPort
IOCompletionPort port; 

// Construct the thread pool
HANDLE* hThreads = new HANDLE[dwThreadCount];
for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwThreadCount; ++i) {
    // The threads run CompletionThread
    hThreads[i] = CreateThread(0, 0, IOCompletionThread, &port, 0, NULL);
}
```

This seems to me to indicate that somehow there is a "carrying capacity" associated with the `IoCompletionPort`. But how is this manifest? I have a hard time seeing how (or even why this would be desirable) a thread with access to the completion port would be prevent from dequeuing from the completion port.

In fact, I tried modifying the line that creates the threads to be `new HANDLE[++dwThreadCount]` (and removing the `const` specifier from the declaration) and the example seemed to execute without complaints. I just noticed one extra timeout error at the conclusion of execution.

My only current conclusion would be to say that `NumberOfConcurrentThreads` is a "dummy" variable with no practical usage, so what am I missing?

Comment: I would assume that if you pass say 1, and create 4 threads, only one thread will be allowed to process requests at a time - that is, at any given time 3 of them will b blocked waiting for work.

Comment: tbh I have a hard time seeing how that is since the actual dequeuing would be a (relatively) small number of machine instructions (a single call to `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`). It's hardly blocking unless substantial time is involved

Comment: Side note: not sure either answer explicitly addresses the "small number of instructions" concern, but it's all about how many threads associated with an IOCP can be in a non-suspended state at a given time. The accepted answer demonstrates this implicitly (and I can see benefit to it in order to avoid race conditions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IOCP is based on the [`KQUEUE` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549547%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
struct KQUEUE {
    DISPATCHER_HEADER Header;
    LIST_ENTRY EntryListHead;
    ULONG CurrentCount;
    ULONG MaximumCount;
    LIST_ENTRY ThreadListHead;
};
```

`MaximumCount` is assigned by `KeNumberProcessors` if initialized by `KeInitializeQueue` (with Count == 0) or `NumberOfConcurrentThreads` if initialized from CreateIoCompletionPort (ZwCreateIoCompletion).

`CurrentCount` is the number of 'active' (not waited) threads, bound to this `KQUEUE` (in the `ETHREAD` structure there is a special field: `KQUEUE* Queue`).

If a thread tries to remove a packet from `KQUEUE` by calling `KeRemoveQueue` or `ZwRemoveIoCompletion` (`GetQueuedCompletionStatus`) and no packets are in the IOCP (`EntryListHead` is empty), then of course the thread will enter a wait state.

But if a packets exists, the system looks at `CurrentCount` and `MaximumCount`. If `CurrentCount < MaximumCount`, a packet will be removed (and `CurrentCount++` incremented). Otherwise, the thread will enter a wait state.

If a thread inserts a new packet to an IOCP which other threads were previously waiting on, one will be awoken (in LIFO order) only if (`CurrentCount < MaximumCount`).

When:

- A thread begins waiting on some object (by `KeWaitForObject`)
- A thread is suspended (this is also call to `KeWaitForObject` internally)
- `KeDelayExecution` (Sleep) is called

the system looks at `Thread->Queue` and if it's not `0`, `CurrentCount--` is decremented. Additionally, If packets exist in the IOCP, threads are waiting on it, and `CurrentCount < MaximumCount` then one thread will be awoken.

So the logic is actually quite complex, but the main point is not more than `MaximumCount` threads will be able to process packets from an IOCP at once.

Usually, the best value for this is `KeNumberProcessors`, but (in some special cases) profiling tools may help you decide on a different value that is more preferable for your situation.

Comment: I proposed an edit to your post to help its readability. I'm not sure I got the detail in the third to last paragraph quite right. But overall, this was very helpful! Thanks :)

Comment: Nice answer RbMm. Does this rule apply to GetQueuedCompletionStatus if a timeout interval is given? will the timeout take into consideration the value of NumberOfConcurrentThreads or it will unblock for timeout ignoring that value?

Comment: @amaninlove - the `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` of course return not late than timeout time.

Comment: What i meant is will a timeout value also abide by that NumberOfConcurrentThreads value and follow the rules if there maximum concurrent reached? or is it just meant for packets dequeuing?

Comment: @amaninlove - the *NumberOfConcurrentThreads* not affect timeout. if current count of active (not waiting) threads which binded to iocp (*Thread->Queue*) >=*NumberOfConcurrentThreads* - the  *GetQueuedCompletionStatus* not pop packet even if exist packets in *iocp*, but if timeout will be - the *GetQueuedCompletionStatus*  of course just return control

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I have not seen msdn mentioning anything about that part.

Comment: @amaninlove - in msdn exist completed and exactly description. *If a completion packet does not appear within the specified time, the function times out, returns FALSE, and sets *lpOverlapped to NULL.*. from self can add - `GetLastError()` in this case return `ERROR_TIMEOUT`

Comment: @amaninlove the *NumberOfConcurrentThreads* at all unrelated to wait timeout. `NumberOfConcurrentThreads` related to active threads, related to return or no packet from queue. but of course not to timeout. in any api - if we use timeout - api return not latter this timeout

Answer (score 3):

The I/O Completion Port itself does not create threads.  The `NumberOfConcurrentThreads` parameter specifies how many threads are allowed to process completion packets in parallel at the same time.  This is explained in more detailed on another MSDN page:

[I/O Completion Ports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198.aspx)

> **How I/O Completion Ports Work**
>
> ...
>
> Although any number of threads can call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` for a specified I/O completion port, when a specified thread calls `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` the first time, it becomes associated with the specified I/O completion port until one of three things occurs: The thread exits, specifies a different I/O completion port, or closes the I/O completion port. In other words, a single thread can be associated with, at most, one I/O completion port.
>
> When a completion packet is queued to an I/O completion port, the system first checks how many threads associated with that port are running. **If the number of threads running is less than the concurrency value (discussed in the next section), one of the waiting threads (the most recent one) is allowed to process the completion packet**. When a running thread completes its processing, it typically calls `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` again, at which point it either returns with the next completion packet or waits if the queue is empty.
>
> ...
>
> **Threads and Concurrency**
>
> The most important property of an I/O completion port to consider carefully is the concurrency value. **The concurrency value of a completion port is specified when it is created with `CreateIoCompletionPort` via the `NumberOfConcurrentThreads` parameter**. This value limits the number of runnable threads associated with the completion port. When the total number of runnable threads associated with the completion port reaches the concurrency value, the system blocks the execution of any subsequent threads associated with that completion port until the number of runnable threads drops below the concurrency value.
>
> The most efficient scenario occurs when there are completion packets waiting in the queue, but no waits can be satisfied because the port has reached its concurrency limit. Consider what happens with a concurrency value of one and multiple threads waiting in the `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` function call. In this case, if the queue always has completion packets waiting, when the running thread calls `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`, it will not block execution because, as mentioned earlier, the thread queue is LIFO. Instead, this thread will immediately pick up the next queued completion packet. No thread context switches will occur, because the running thread is continually picking up completion packets and the other threads are unable to run.
>
> ...
>
> **The best overall maximum value to pick for the concurrency value is the number of CPUs on the computer. If your transaction required a lengthy computation, a larger concurrency value will allow more threads to run**. Each completion packet may take longer to finish, but more completion packets will be processed at the same time. You can experiment with the concurrency value in conjunction with profiling tools to achieve the best effect for your application.
>
> The system also allows a thread waiting in `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` to process a completion packet if another running thread associated with the same I/O completion port enters a wait state for other reasons, for example the `SuspendThread` function. When the thread in the wait state begins running again, **there may be a brief period when the number of active threads exceeds the concurrency value**. However, the system quickly reduces this number by not allowing any new active threads until the number of active threads falls below the concurrency value. This is one reason to have your application create more threads in its thread pool than the concurrency value. Thread pool management is beyond the scope of this topic, but a good rule of thumb is to have a minimum of twice as many threads in the thread pool as there are processors on the system. For additional information about thread pooling, see [Thread Pools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686760.aspx).

Comment: So in summary: the windows API maintains a buffer of thread identification of size `NumberOfConcurrentThreads`. If a thread enters a wait state, it is removed from this buffer and its next call to `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` may be blocked if the buffer is filled. Also, there may be practical design reasons to have more threads prepared than `NumberOfConcurrentThreads` if there is a chance of your threads going into a suspended or wait state. Sound accurate?

Comment: no any buffer of threads. when thread go to wait state - system look are it associated with some IOCP (KQUEUE object) and if yes - KiActivateWaiterQueue is called current number of threads processing entries for the queue is decrement and an attempt is made to activate another thread if the current count  is less than the maximum count, there is a waiting thread, and the queue is not empty.

Comment: @RbMm so instead of a buffer it's a simple counter. Is there a separate kind of wait state from the blocking done by `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` when waiting on an IO to dequeu (I'm assuming it would be implemented as an efficient wait instead of a busy wait)? I've always thought of the threading model as 3 states, but there's probably more I imagine...

Comment: yes, it's a simple counter - look for https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549547%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 - KQUEUE - this is IOCP internal. no separate kind of wait state

Comment: @RbMm so in the case where there are no packets currently in the queue, all threads will be in a wait state and any thread could theoretically grab an item from the queue? (I think this is the last bit of info to understanding my question)

Comment: ULONG MaximumCount; - here stored NumberOfConcurrentThreads, CurrentCount - how many threads binded to this IOCP active. so if CurrentCount become >= MaximumCount new call to remove packet from IOCP not return just, even if exist ready packets in IOCP. will be wait, until  CurrentCount < MaximumCount. every time when any thread begin wait(by any reason), system check - are in bunded to IOCP. and if yes - decrement CurrentCount . if it become less than MaximumCount, some thread wait on IOCP and packet in IOCP - thread awaken

Comment: @RbMm Awesome, if you were to summarize this in an answer I would accept it :) (I've upvoted this answer)

Comment: threads call KeRemoveQueue or ZwRemoveIoCompletion(GetQueuedCompletionStatus) - if no packets in queue or CurrentCount become >= MaximumCount - thread begin wait. in another case - packet removed and pass to thread